# Create a discount code for my own app in google play store

Tags: android, discount

Is it possible with google play store having a non free app that can be downloaded for free (or with a certain discount) if the user provide a promotional code?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Have you found any idea? Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found that it is impossible to make a discount for paid app in play store.

Answer (score 4):

As of now, no you are unable to create a promo code for your app in the Play Store. I recommend at looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10080005/2168085) for more details. Please let me know if this answers your question.